# How to delete user from table and database ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i'm building a simple table from a mysql database with crud functionality.

Im having issues creating the vanilla JS needed to delete each user from the table and database when the delete button is clicked.

Each row represents each user and each row has a delete button populated inside it.

Is there a way to assign each delete button to each user and then delete them when the button is clicked?

As you can see in the first function a table is produced with the data from the database[image]

here is my index.js and my delete.php files for reference:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "data.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length === 0) {
                alert('No record found');
            } else {
                var tableBody = "";
                data.forEach(function(row) {
                    tableBody += "<tr>";
                    tableBody += "<td id='user-id'>" + row.id +  "</td>";
                    tableBody += "<td>" + row.name + "</td>";
                    tableBody += "<td>" + row.email + "</td>";
                    tableBody += "<td>" + row.city + "</td>";
                    tableBody += "<td> <button id='edit' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button> <button id='delete' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button> </td>" 
                    tableBody += "</tr>";
                });
                document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = tableBody;
                console.warn(xhr.responseText)
            }
            
        } else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert("An error occurred while fetching the data.");
        }
    };
    xhr.send();       
});



// function to submit new user info into the database 

const saveForm = document.querySelector("#save-data");


saveForm.addEventListener('submit', function() {

  const modalMess = document.getElementById("response");

  const userData = {
    name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
    email: document.querySelector('#email').value,
    city: document.querySelector('#city').value
  };

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(userData);

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'adduser.php');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        modalMess.innerHTML = xhr.responseText
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.error('Error: ' + xhr.status);
    }
  };

  xhr.send(jsonData);
});



// Get all the delete buttons
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#delete');

// Add an event listener to each delete button click event
deleteButtons.forEach(function(deleteButton) {
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // Find the ID element in the same row as the clicked delete button
    const userId = this.closest('tr').querySelector('#user-id').textContent;

    // Send an AJAX request to the server to delete the user
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'delete.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      } else {
        console.error('Error: ' + xhr.status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ id: userId }));
  });
});



PHP FILE 

<?php
header('Content-Type:application/json');
header('Access-control-Allow-Origin:*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Acess-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Acess-Control-Allow-Methods,Authorization,X-Requested-With');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$student_id = $data['id'];


include "connect.php";
$sql = "DELETE FROM clients WHERE id={$student_id}";
//   $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo json_encode(array("message" => "Delete sucessfully", "status" => true));
} else {
   echo json_encode(array("message" => "not deleted", "status" => false));
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple buttons with the same ID. IDs in a HTML document  must be unique (as they must in many other walks of life!). Use a class instead to work with querySelectorAll

Comment: You can assign the unique user id value to delete button's id value. That way each button can have a unique id value, and use the clicked button's id value in your onclick event listener.

Answer (score 1):

In the web page with the button to click for deleting a user:

```
<script>
function delUser(user) {
    url = "deluser.php?name=" + user;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

<?PHP
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        ...
        echo "<button class=bigRed onClick=\"delUser('$user')\">";
        echo     "Delete";
        echo "</button>";
    }
```

In deluser.php:

```
$name = @$_GET['name'];
...
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE name = ?";
...  (and suitably bind $name into the query and perform it.)
...  (use mysqli or PDO, whichever you are used to.)
```

The button may need `type=button` or `type=submit` depending on whether it is part of a `<form>`.

This won't respond to the PHP; you may want to check the response to see the the deletion was successful.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure your use case but I would suggest using an MVC framework and not mix code like this. Laravel is the norm but there are easier lightweight alternatives like codeigniter as well.

Comming back to your problem, I suggest using "data" attributes in your buttons e.g. "data-id=1"

Then in your event listerner - you can read the "id" by using:

```
deleteButton.getAttribute("data-id")
```

Read more on how attributes work here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute